# Find specific place in div where text occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="score-data">
    <h4>Soccer League</h4>
    <span>14:00</span>
    TeamA - TeamB
    <a href="/match/pveAhZ4U/?s=1" class="fin">3:0</a>
    <br>
    <span>14:00</span>
    TeamC - TeamD
    <a href="/match/OO61fezI/?s=1" class="fin">0:1</a>
    <br><span>15:00</span>
    TeamE - TeamF
    <a href="/match/z3zKCxjn/?s=1" class="fin">3:0</a>
</div>
```

This is just a sample, there are hundreds of identical HTML patterns within the same `div`. What I need to do is use jQuery to find the `href` corresponding to a certain team. I thought I could try something like:

```
var a = $("#score-data:contains('TeamC')").closest('a').attr('href');
```

But it returns `undefined`, I suspect because it is only looking for the closest `a` tag to the outer `div`, which obviously doesn't help. How can I do this with jQuery?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4QpX/1/) with the working sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/y9JLL/)</kbd>

```
var href = $("#score-data a").filter(function () {
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('TeamC') > -1;
}).attr('href');
alert(href);
```

---

Look for links `$("#score-data a")` then filter `.filter()` by previous (text) node's value `this.previousSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('TeamC') > -1;`.

---

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[node.previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling)

[node.nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue)

[str.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Ah, of course! Looking for links, then filtering by previous (text) node's value is better than collecting all text nodes then going down for `<a>` elements. Upvote. )